# The message transmitted from the server to the client does not appear

Tags: c++, winsock2

I am writing a client-server application in C ++ (Visual Studio 2017) using WinSock2. I looked at the YouTube tutorial, made a server and client. When launched, the connection is established.
But the message from the server is not transmitted to the client.

Here is my server.

```
//Server
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    //WinSock Startup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) { //If WSAStartup returns anything ither than 0, than that means an error has occured in the WinSock Startup
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "WinSock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr; //Address tha the will bind our listening socket to
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr); //lenght of the address (required for accept call)
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //Broadcast locally
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111); //Port
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //IPv4 Socket

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); //Create socket to listen for new connections
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)); //Bind the address to the socket
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN); //Places sListen socket in a state in which is in listening for an incoming connection. Note: SOMAXCONN = Socket Outstanding Max Connections

    SOCKET newConnection; // Socket to hold the client's connection
    newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen); //Accept a new connection
    if (newConnection == 0) { //If accepting the client's connection failed
        std::cout << "Failed to accept the client's connection" << std::endl;
    }
    else { //If client connection properly accepted
        std::cout << "Client connected!" << std::endl;
        char MOID[256] = "Welcome! This is a Message of the Day."; //Create buffer with message of the day
        send(newConnection, MOID, sizeof(MOID), NULL); //Send MOID buffer
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is such a client.

```
//Client
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    //WinSock Startup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) { //If WSAStartup returns anything ither than 0, than that means an error has occured in the WinSock Startup
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "WinSock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); 
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr; //Address to be binded to our Connection socket
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr); //Need sizeofaddr for the connect function
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //Address = localhoct (this pc)
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111); //Port =  1111
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //IPv4 Socket

    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); //Set connection socket
    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeofaddr) != 0) { //If we are unable to connect...
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to connect", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0; //Failed to connect
    }
    std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
    char MOID[256];
    recv(Connection, MOID, sizeof(MOID), NULL); //Recieve Message of the day  buffer into MOID array 
    std::cout << "MOID:" << std::endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

This message should be transmitted: "Welcome! This is a Message of the Day." Please tell me why the message is not transmitted, and how can I fix this?

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: In the client, I have to write ```std::cout << "MOID:" << MOID << std::endl;``` instead of ```std::cout << "MOID:" << std::endl;```, sory.

Answer (score 2):

> This message should be transmitted: "Welcome! This is a Message of the Day."

Your expectation is wrong. TCP socket is a stream socket (as suggested by SOCK_STREAM parameter) which means that it has certain properties. For stream it means that data will be receieved in the same order it was sent (or you get an error). Nobody guarantees though that you will get whole message as one packet. You may get them byte by byte or groups of 2 bytes, or whole message or any other variant. So your program should handle any of that - read data in a loop until you get your whole message. How you would know that whole message received? It is up to you - some send message size beforehand, some use end of message marker (which could be `'\0'` symbol of your message). But expecting that you get whole message in one shot is just wrong, it does not work that way. In addition to that you need to check what `recv()` returns - ie how many bytes it received or if there any error happened.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. In my case, everything turned out to be simpler: in ```cout``` I did not specify the MOID array itself, I just signed it.

Comment: @e7min in TCP, there is no guarantee that `send(newConnection, MOID, sizeof(MOID), NULL);` will send the entire `MOID` in 1 go, or that `recv(Connection, MOID, sizeof(MOID), NULL)` will receive the entire `MOID`. You are ignoring the return values, which tell you how many bytes were actually sent/received. If the return is `< sizeof(MOID)` then you have to call `send()`/`recv()` again for the remaining bytes. There are NUMEROUS questions on StackOverflow, and tutorials elsewhere, that cover this in detail.